# Apply html elements in php statement

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, php

I know this is probably going to sound like a beginner question ... to which it is in some sort.

I have this statement in my one plugin that i am working on:

```
add_post_meta($newpostid, 'name', $formdata['your-first-name'].$formdata['your-last-name']);
```

Which in turn will add FirstnameLastname in a custom field.

What i would like to do is add a space between the first and last name like this:

Firstname Lastname

I have tried using statements such as:

```
add_post_meta($newpostid, 'name', $formdata['your-first-name']. echo '&nbsp' . $formdata['your-last-name']);
```

But obviously that is not going to parse correctly. Is there any Idea on how I can achieve this?

Any help would be welcome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
add_post_meta($newpostid, 'name', $formdata['your-first-name'] . ' ' . $formdata['your-last-name']);
```

This uses PHP string concatenation to add a space; the `echo` isn't necessary in in this instance because WP will do it itself, later. You probably can't force a non-breaking space there, either, since WP will escape all its output.